# Haskell- Recursively calling on a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, recursion, tuples

I have the following code that I am working on.  I am attempting to recursively call upon the next element in the list `[(Int,Int)]` if the conditional checkerAlive is True. I am not sure how to go about making the recursive call.

```
    makemoves :: (Int,[Char],[[Char]],[(Int,Int)]) -> (Int,[Char],[[Char]])


    makemoves (time, captures, board, [(moveFrom, moveTo)] ) 
        |checkerAlive ( board) == True = onemove (time,captures,board,(moveFrom,moveTo))
        |otherwise = reset (time, captures, board)
```

Comment: What does ``onemove`` return?

Comment: `onemove` returns `(Int,[Char],[[Char]]) `. Which is the time, captures, and board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `[(Int, Int)]` for the `moves` parameter, and the match you're performing is `[(moveFrom, moveTo)]`, but this will *only* match a single element list, and nothing more.  What you probably want is more like

```
makemoves (time, captures, board, (moveFrom, moveTo):moves)
```

Then you can make the recursive call on `moves`, although I don't know where you want to put the recursion without having more of your code.

---

If you split out your game state from the moves to have two parameters, you might make this a bit easier:

```
makemoves :: (Int, String, [String]) -> [(Int, Int)] -> (Int, String, [String])
makemoves gameState [] = gameState
makemoves (time, captures, board) ((moveFrom, moveTo):moves)
    | checkerAlive board = makemoves (onemove (time, captures, board, (moveFrom, moveTo))) moves
    | otherwise          = reset (time, captures, board)
```

Note that this is just a guess of what you want to do with this function, I don't know what you actually want to do.  I've also added in the case for when the moves list is empty, and changed `checkerAlive (board) == True` to simply `checkerAlive board`, since checking if a boolean is `True` always gives you that boolean, it's redundant.  You might want to make the same change with `onemove` so that it accepts two parameters:

```
onemove :: (Int, String, [String]) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, String, [String])
onemove (time, captures, board) (moveFrom, moveTo) = ...
```

---

At this point it would probably be worth your time to introduce at least a type alias for your game state:

```
type GameState = (Int, String, [String])
```

And one for a move

```
type Move = (Int, Int)
```

Then you can write your functions as

```
makemoves :: GameState -> [Move] -> GameState
makemoves gameState [] = gameState
makemoves gameState@(_, _, board) (move:moves)
    | checkerAlive board = makemoves (onemove gameState move) moves
    | otherwise          = reset gameState

onemove :: GameState -> Move -> GameState
onemove (time, captures, board) (moveFrom, moveTo) = ...
```

With this factored out like this, hopefully it's easier to see how your application logic is actually put together, and how you don't need to treat your list of tuples (moves) any differently than another list.  In `makemoves`, it even appears that you can ignore the fact that they're even tuples and pass it directly to `onemove`, which does care.  Also, I've attempted to show how splitting tuples into multiple parameters can clean up code and make it easier to work with.  A good rule of thumb is to consider if the different parameters are inherently related, or are they meaningful split apart.  If they're inherently related, then tuple 'em together, otherwise leave them separate.  For example, I might make a function

```
rotatePoint :: (Double, Double) -> Double -> (Double, Double)
rotatePoint (x, y) angle = ...
```

Which rotates a point by the given angle about the origin.  The values `x` and `y` are inherently related here, they aren't meaningful separated when talking about transforming points in a plane.  On the other hand, it wouldn't make sense to pass to this function `(x, y, angle)`, since the `angle` really doesn't have anything to do with the point `(x, y)`.  Another good metric to use is whether or not you're returning a tuple as the same type from a function, so here you're returning `(Int, [Char], [[Char]])`, so it might be a good idea to keep those values in tuples throughout your code, and not add any more elements to that tuple.

Comment: I would like to recursively call `moves` within the call `onemove` completes..`onemove` should call upon one tuple in the list of tuples `[(Int, Int)]`

Comment: @Dev What I've shown is what I think you want, you call `onemove` with the first `move` from a list of `moves`, then call `makemoves` on that result with the rest of the `moves`.

Comment: Are you available for chat?  I have a few more questions relative to this problem

Comment: No problem!  That did answer my question.  Thanks again!